# Обучение ПО с++

Tags: c++

Выучил с++ на базовом уровне и хочется двигаться дальше. Заинтересовало написание ПО на с++. Какие есть книги / ресурсы для обучения этому. Язык английский или русский - не важно.

Comment: Фреймворк Qt, автор Шлее.

Comment: Базовый уровень, это какой? C++ - один из самых сложных языков. И когда тебе покажется, что ты уже много знаешь, сделаешь ещё шаг вперед и почувтсвуешь себя профаном =)

Comment: для меня базовый уровень - умение работы с файлами, знание ооп, stl

Comment: Есть огромное количество нюансов. К тому же знание STL подразумевает, например, мультитрединг? А это ведь отдельная область в программировании =)